# Polar decomposition for a real square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

my question is about a statement i've found on a paper that says " For any matrix $A \in SL(2,R)$, by the polar decomposition theorem, one can find numbers $\alpha, \beta \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $c\geq 1$ such that $A = R_{\beta}H_cR_{\alpha}$, where $H_{\theta}$ is a rotation matrix by an angle $\theta$ and $H_c = \begin{pmatrix}
c & 0\\
0 & c^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$."
I know that for real square matrix, like that case, we can decompose $A = RP$, where $R$ is a rotation matrix and $P$ is a scaling matrix. $H_c$ is clearly a scaling matrix, but i'm in doubt how he's applying the theorem, because the matrix $H_cR_{\alpha}$ can't be represented as a scaling matrix, can ? If you have some tip to help me I appreciate it, sorry if my question is kind of dumb. Anyway, thanks !

Comment: $H_cR_\alpha$ is a scaling along a set of orthogonal directions, not necessarily aligned with the coordinate axes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was searching for some results and found out the Singular Value Decomposition theorem, that is a consequence of Polar Decomposition Theorem, and solves that exactly problem.

Comment: Note that the SVD gives you orthogonal matrices, which aren’t necessarily rotations. There are often reflections involved in the $U$ and $V$ matrices. That’s a consequence of singular values always being nonnegative.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to say that, we can choose rotation instead of reflections is the fact that the matrix A has positive determinant. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for some results and found out the Singular Value Decomposition theorem, that is a consequence of Polar Decomposition Theorem, and solves that exactly problem.